# My value reset to zero whenever I refresh my Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working in my Ionic App and in that I am setting and getting the value of the products in the cart means the number of products in the cart but When I refresh or reopen the app, it initially set to zero.

This is my Sevice > **cartservice.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class CartProvider {
subject = new Subject<any>();
constructor(public http: HttpClient, public storage: Storage) {}

public setCart(cart: any) {
  this.subject.next({ cart: cart });
}
public getCart(): Observable<any> {
  return this.subject.asObservable();
}
```

In this ts file, I have made 2 function for setting and getting.

This is my **cart.ts**:

```
cartItems: any[] = [];

loadCartItems() {
   this.cartService
      .getCartItems()
      .then(val => {
        this.cartItems = val;
        this.cartService.setCart(this.cartItems.length);
      })
      .catch(err => {});
}
```

In this ts file, I am setting the value of number of products in the cart.

This is my **app.component.ts**:

```
cartLength: number = 0;
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar,
    public splashScreen: SplashScreen, public events: Events,
    private storage: Storage, public restProvider: RestapiProvider, 
    private cartService: CartProvider) {
     this.cartService.getCart().subscribe(data => {
     this.cartLength = data.cart;
});

}
```

In this ts file, I am getting the number of products value.

This is my **app.html**:

```
<ion-icon name="cart" class="myicon22" (click)="cardpage2()"><ion-badge class="mynewicon11" color="danger">{{cartLength}}</ion-badge></ion-icon>
```

In this html, I am showing the number of products value.

Every thing is working fine but the problem is that when I refresh or reopen my app, it value is initially set to 0, and when I move to the cart page, it takes the value of number of products available in the cart.

I want that it is set to the number of products available in the cart and not to 0 when the user refresh the or reopen the app.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually store your data anywhere? If your data is not stored, it will not be persisted through a refresh.

Comment: @xdecdec. Okay if I store the value and then set the value, it will update or not. Can you help me with the code.

Comment: Can you show your existing code for the storage? If you don't have anything yet, you could start by using the browser's local storage or session storage: https://alligator.io/js/introduction-localstorage-sessionstorage/

Comment: @xdecdec. I am using the storage in my app but can you tell where I should set the storage, in cart.ts or in app.component.ts.

Comment: Ideally your service should handle the logic, while your component displays data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

**In Your Sevice > cartservice.ts:**

```
public setCart(cart: any) {
    this.subject.next({ cart: cart });
    this.storage.set("CARTNU", cart);
  }
  public getCart(): Observable<any> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
```

This code will set the value when you refresh the page and also update the value when you set it. This solved my problem.